# Problems with Web.config not changing in MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a brand new MVC3 application used for testing with a Web.Config looking like this:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="aa.htm"
    mode="Off" >
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="aaa.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```

I have a Web.Debug.config that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I build my project with the "Debug" setting and then check the obj folder then I just don't see my changes getting applied. I thought before that I saw a folder with transformed and original web configs but now I see nothing.

Note this is a brand new application and I didn't change anything else. The customErrors in the Web.Config is in the correct place under system.web.

Finally I set the solution configuration to Debug and clicked on the green arrow next to that.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Ronald04 what you expect this setting to do to the application?

Comment: I believe I found out the problem. I need to click "show all files" to unshow and then again click "show all files" to show again. This seems to do a refresh. I just thought it would refresh automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it always visible by.

- Right Click on item.
- Include In Project.